# The animation in the Canvas is not working

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I have written a simple code to get the context of the canvas and add two Rectange Objects so as to draw them to the canvas. My Problem is that I am not able to animate them because when I try to use context.clearRect() ; it throws an error stating that the context is undefined. But is there otherwise even the draw method which I have wont work. I am not able to figure out the solution. The errors that I saw was on Firebug console. I have my code on fiddle at

http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/b8cKZ/

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(refresh, 1000);
```

is the problem. You are calling this function but you are not passing the parameters. It's also not necessary to have `refresh` require parameters since you declared the necessary variables as global.

Answer (score 0):

```
drawObj.push(new Rectangle("20", "20", "30", "40", "#3A5BCD"));
drawObj.push(new Rectangle("50", "50", "100", "30", "#EF2B36"));
```

You're passing strings for x, y, width and height.

```
objArray[i].width=objArray[i].width+j;
objArray[i].height=objArray[i].height+j;
```

...so this does string concatenation, which means width ends up being a string saying "3000000000000000000000"...

You should learn to use Chrome's debugger (control+shift+j), it's really easy to find problems like this with it.

Also use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) instead of setTimeout and don't pointlessly re-draw everything 100 times per frame :)